# File not exist android image taken by camera

Tags: android

I have a problem while getting an image taken by the camera in my app.

When I try to get the file, it doesn't exists. I don't see where the problem is:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            Uri uri = Uri.parse("/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg");
            Intent photoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            photoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);

            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        File image=new File("/sdcard/Images/","test_image.jpg");
        if (image.exists()){
             Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg");
             ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object
             byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        }
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
}
```

When it reach to image.exists() it says false. I already wrote sd write permissions on manifest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Uri.parse](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) Creates a uri which parses the given encoded URI string instead of file path with is not exist on sdcard. so either user `"file://"+ filename_with_path` or use [Uri.fromFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#fromFile%28java.io.File%29)  to create URI from file path. also use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead of static path for sdcard as:

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
file = new File(dir, "test_image.jpg");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

Intent photoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
photoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
startActivityForResult(photoIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

**Second** major issue is you are passing `cameraIntent` intent in which you are not adding `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` to `startActivityForResult`. so pass photoIntent to startActivityForResult because you are adding MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT key in photoIntent Intent instance instead of `cameraIntent` .

Comment: Now it find the image so it goes inside the condition. It fails because of bitmapFactory.decode... How do I get the url or the directory? with dir variable? Well, I guess I have to check about that but the question is solved. so Thank you  man.

Comment: @Biribu : inside onActivityResult you can get file path as: `File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();File image=new File(dir,"test_image.jpg"); if (image.exists()){
             Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath());`

Answer (score 2):

You can check your path and if your folder exists with this :

```
File[] file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();
```

It gives you the sdcard path and all its folders.